# Cannot Load Oracle Assembly in ASP.Net MVC Application using Visual Studio Express 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have a Windows 7 machine.

Creating an ASP.Net MVC3 project using Visual Studio Express 2010.

Require the Oracle.DataAccess.dll (odp.net).

Will be deployed on 64 bit server, so 64 bit is preferable, but 32bit is fine, too. So first I tried leaving things at the default setting ("any cpu"), but I get the message that the Oracle dll can't be loaded because it is in the wrong format.

In configuration manager, I set to 86x and then I load the Oracle.dataaccess.dll version 2x as a reference.  Compile, and I no longer get the Oracle dll message.  But I can't load the MVC framework.  I get a message saying global.asax is unable to inherit from myproject.mvcapplication because the assembly can't be found.

I have discovered that my various dlls (entityframework as well as the project dll) must be stored in "bin/" for the MVCFramework to be detectable.  But if I change the output compile folder to be bin instead of bin/x86/debug, I get the Oracle load error again.  I can make it work - if I compile and output to bin/x86/debug and then copy all the resulting dlls into bin/.  But I shouldn't have to do that!

I have the same exact problem if I try x64 instead of x86 (using Oracle.dataaccess.dll v4).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Oracle drivers are the recommended way to go at this point with .net (mvc / web forms)
2. EntityFramework is in Beta for Oracle, I have had email conversations with 2 guys from Oracle.  If you are using Oracle 9 don't bother with EF period (sprocs not working),  but for 10.xxx  should work, but not production ready.
3. Are you on windows 2003 or 2008 server?  I had lots of issues with 2008 with 64 bit, and changed in IIS to run 32 bit.... that worked until the Oracle Access Manager (OAM) / webgate that was being used was 64 bit... thus it was a no-way.
4. Under references of your Oracle.DataAccess , are you setting "copy local" to "true" ( you should be).
5. Install the MVC 3 tools update on the server that helps a lot.
6. Are you saying it is working on your local machine with windows 7 or not?
7. please paste some specific error messages and be as thorough in responding as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  Re: pt1:  I'll look into this today pt 2:  We have Oracle 11g.  pt3: It will be Windows 2008.  Currently I am just working on my development box.  pt 4 & 5:  I'll check that today pt6: I am just working on my development box right now and I have Windows 7.  It is not working.  pt 7:  I'll test today and send along the specific messages.

Comment: Since I had documented a lot of my research. Here you go.  1. [link](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/microsoft-dotnet-oracle-driver.aspx)

Comment: Since I had documented a lot of my research. Here you go.  1. [Oracle Driver Performance](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/microsoft-dotnet-oracle-driver.aspx) 2. Good that you have 11g , alex.keh@oracle.com is who I communicated with.  Based on [Oracle EF Forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1059538) and [Beta 2 EF for Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html) Not recommended for production.

Comment: Ok - I am not using the latest beta release.  I am using "64-bit ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) for Windows x64" found on this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html But it looks like I need to try the one found here for 32 bit: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html  I think I have a conflict somewhere and my program must have mixed 32/64 stuff going on.

Comment: I think that you are on the right track. One thing I recall at my last job was conflicts with the Oracle drivers installed on my local machine (also same issues with web server). The way .NET worked with the GAC is a blessing but still a curse.  Be great if all you and I and others need to do was place drivers into your references / bin -but it seems that looking into your environment variables to see where Oracle_Home is pointing to.  Thus  C:\Oracle or another location WILL affect your success. I prefer the Microsoft drivers, but between MS support and performance, Oracle drivers are best.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  It prompted me to look more closely at the Oracle dll I had grabbed.  I switched to 32 and all worked.  I had thought I had both 32 and 64, but I didn't. I set my configuration to "any cpu" and add a reference to the 32 bit, framework 4, dll, and it compiles and runs.

Comment: Yes, I recall doing that with IIS on a 2008 server R2, but then ran into the OAM/Webgate for the company mandatory Single Sign On etc.. which was 64 bit, and that became as nightmare.  Good to hear it is fixed!